# Incomplete Response Received From Application + Status Code 502: How to Connect Node.js Express Application & MongoDB database with Phusion Passenger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passenger

My Node.js/Express & MongoDB application works well locally.

However, it doesn't work on **production mode**.

Indeed, I'm using o2switch hosting which uses **Phusion Passenger** through the cPanel.

I think the issue is that my MongoDB database is not connected to my app anymore because of the following snippet provided by Passenger for connection:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}
 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var body = 'Hello World';
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
    res.end(body);
});
 
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    app.listen(3000);
}
```

Indeed, I tried to custom this snapshot and adapt it to my code, but I wasn't able to do it.

As you can see below, I couldn't manage to implement the code related to the MongoDB database in the Passenger code:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    app.listen(3000);
}

db.connectToDatabase()
  .then(function () {
    app.listen(port);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
  });
```

On the browser, the following error message displays:

> Incomplete response received from application

When, I console log, it says that it is a **status code 502** error.

Here is my code related to the MongoDB database to run my app locally:

**database.js:**

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let database;

async function connect() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
  database = client.db('com4muz-blog');
}

function getDb() {
  if (!database) {
    throw { message: 'Database connection not established!' };
  }
  return database;
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase: connect,
  getDb: getDb
};
```

**app.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const sessionConfig = require('./config/session');

const db = require('./data/database');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin/blog');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/admin/auth');

const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/home/default');
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/home/posts');
const quotationsRoutes = require('./routes/home/quotations');
const contactsRoutes = require('./routes/home/contacts');

const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth-middleware');

const mongoDbSessionStore = sessionConfig.createSessionStore(session);

const app = express();

app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/home'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin')
]);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/public/admin/images', express.static('public/admin/images'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(session(sessionConfig.createSessionConfig(mongoDbSessionStore)));

app.use(authMiddleware);

app.use('/', adminRoutes);
app.use('/', authRoutes);

app.use('/', defaultRoutes);
app.use('/', postsRoutes);
app.use('/', quotationsRoutes);
app.use('/', contactsRoutes);

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).render('404');
});

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(500).render('500');
});

db.connectToDatabase().then(function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Now, here is my code which I'm using to run my app on production mode via **Phusion Passenger**:

**database.js:**

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let database;

let mongodbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
let MONGODB_URL = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.42o6qd6.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

if (process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
  mongodbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
}

async function connect() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl);
  database = client.db('com4muz-blog');
}

function getDb() {
  if (!database) {
    throw { message: 'Database connection not established!' };
  }
  return database;
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase: connect,
  getDb: getDb
};
```

**app.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const sessionConfig = require('./config/session');

const db = require('./data/database');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin/blog');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/admin/auth');

const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/home/default');
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/home/posts');
const quotationsRoutes = require('./routes/home/quotations');
const contactsRoutes = require('./routes/home/contacts');

const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth-middleware');

const mongoDbSessionStore = sessionConfig.createSessionStore(session);

let port = 3000;

if (process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
  port = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
}

const app = express();

app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/home'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin')
]);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/public/admin/images', express.static('public/admin/images'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(session(sessionConfig.createSessionConfig(mongoDbSessionStore)));

app.use(authMiddleware);

app.use('/', adminRoutes);
app.use('/', authRoutes);

app.use('/', defaultRoutes);
app.use('/', postsRoutes);
app.use('/', quotationsRoutes);
app.use('/', contactsRoutes);

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).render('404');
});

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(500).render('500');
});

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    app.listen(3000);
}

// db.connectToDatabase()
//   .then(function () {
//     app.listen(port);
//   })
//   .catch(function (error) {
//     console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
//   });
```

As you can see, it seems like the code doesn't able the connection to the database.

However, I'm not able to find the right code for that with Passenger, eventhough I tried as follows:

**app.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const sessionConfig = require('./config/session');

const db = require('./data/database');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin/blog');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/admin/auth');

const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/home/default');
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/home/posts');
const quotationsRoutes = require('./routes/home/quotations');
const contactsRoutes = require('./routes/home/contacts');

const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth-middleware');

const mongoDbSessionStore = sessionConfig.createSessionStore(session);

let port = 3000;

if (process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
  port = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
}

const app = express();

app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/home'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin')
]);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/public/admin/images', express.static('public/admin/images'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(session(sessionConfig.createSessionConfig(mongoDbSessionStore)));

app.use(authMiddleware);

app.use('/', adminRoutes);
app.use('/', authRoutes);

app.use('/', defaultRoutes);
app.use('/', postsRoutes);
app.use('/', quotationsRoutes);
app.use('/', contactsRoutes);

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).render('404');
});

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(500).render('500');
});

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    db.connectToDatabase()
    .then(function () {
      app.listen('passenger');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
    });
} else {
    db.connectToDatabase()
    .then(function () {
      app.listen(port);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
    });
}
```

Indeed, I changed the code logic for connecting MongoDB database with Passenger, as below:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
        PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
    }
    
    if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
        db.connectToDatabase()
        .then(function () {
          app.listen('passenger');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
        });
    } else {
        db.connectToDatabase()
        .then(function () {
          app.listen(port);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
        });
    }
```

Edit: Here is the error that appears in the logs on the access to the blog:

> App 814821 output: node:internal/process/promises:279 App 814821
> output: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */); App
> 814821 output: ^ App 814821 output: [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#".] {
> App 814821 output: code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' App 814821 output:
> } [ W 2022-11-19 10:30:01.7998 813657/Tg
> age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 5-1] Sending 502 response:
> application did not send a complete response [ N 2022-11-19
> 10:30:01.8095 813657/Ti age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1147 ]: Checking whether
> to disconnect long-running connections for process 814821, application
> /home/raso1970/node-com4muz (development) App 815207 output:
> node:internal/process/promises:279 App 815207 output:
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */); App 815207
> output: ^ App 815207 output: [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error
> originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
> catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
> .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#".] { App
> 815207 output: code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' App 815207 output: } [
> W 2022-11-19 10:30:03.7100 813657/Ti age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96
> ]: [Client 6-1] Sending 502 response: application did not send a
> complete response [ W 2022-11-19 10:30:05.0596 813657/T3
> age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:102 ]: Process (pid=815207,
> group=/home/raso1970/node-com4muz (development)) no longer exists!
> Detaching it from the pool. [ N 2022-11-19 10:30:05.0597 813657/T3
> age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1147 ]: Checking whether to disconnect
> long-running connections for process 815207, application
> /home/raso1970/node-com4muz (development)

It seems that an error is returned by the application so the server has no response to send, it is interrupted by the error.
I don't have details on what is causing the error, but it may be related to MondoDB. It should be checked in the code if the connection is done correctly.

Actually, the error simply says that there is a promise or async function that encounters an error and doesn't have a catch handler added. Since I call catch on the promise returned when trying to connect to my db, it is unlikely that is where this error is coming from. The complete code of my application contains a lot of other async codes, so I cannot say where the issue lies, but I think the db is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

Basically, **my Node.js/Express app wasn't connected at all to my MongoDB Atlas database**.

So, I had to change the code logic related to the connection to the db in app.js, as follows:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
    db.connectToDatabase()
      .then(function () {
          app.listen('passenger');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
      });
} else {
    db.connectToDatabase()
      .then(function () {
          app.listen(port);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('La connexion à la base de données a échoué !');
      });
}
```

However, this change wasn't enough, because I had to set the `MONGODB_URL` environment variable for my web app differently.

Basically, I had to set the `MONGODB_URL` to the correct connection string for my database. Besides that, I picked a name for the environment variable to pass in the port to my app, and then set it to the port number I want.

Indeed, when I was reading the port, I wanted the name of the environment variable with the port value, not the one with the mongo db url. However, I was before this change, reading the port from `process.env.MONGODB_URL` which is the environment variable I use to provide the mongo db url.

1. So, the first change, I did it by editing the `.htaccess` file of my site:

Therefore, there are two of doing this:

- One way to do this is to set the following config line in your apache config (inside your site's virtualhost block):

**SetEnv MONGODB_URL the_correct_value_goes_here**

- Another way is to export it from your user's shell, assuming a bash shell, that would go in the .bashrc file in your home directory on the server and look like this:

**export MONGODB_URL="the_correct_value_goes_here"**

2. Then, I change the MONGODB_URL environment variable name in app.js, as follows:

I replaced `MONGODB_URL` with something else like `APP_PORT_NUMBER` or something.

So, I replaced this bit of code:

```
if (process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
  port = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
}
```

by this one:

```
if (process.env.APP_PORT_NUMBER) {
  port = process.APP_PORT_NUMBER;
}
```

Edit: `export` **is not an Apache config option**, you can't put that one in the `.htaccess` file. However, you can put the `SetEnv` in the `.htaccess` though.